# I wish to move SBC flash image to new board and maintain network interface indexing

Tags: linux, ethernet, network-interface, interface

I wrote a small php application on a SBC. I created a disk image from the CF card. When I write the image to a new CF and install on a new SBC the interface index numbers (I hope I am stating that correctly) change. For instance - the interface numbers on the original board are eth0, eth1, etc. When I move the disk image to a new board the interfaces are added as eth5, eth6, etc. 
My real question is, is there a way to maintain the original indexing?

There is probably a better way to articulate my question so feel free to point out my ignorance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished by deleting the network interface definitions in \etc\udev\rules.d\70-persistent-net.rules

Generally these definitions start with:

# PCI device